# Yii2 images to have checkbox list in the search form

Tags: image, search, checkbox, yii2, active-form

In my yii2 project I want to get checkbox for my images in order to search by images. Whenever the users checks the checkbox and submits the button, it should display the content only with those checked images.

**My checkbox list**

```
  <?php $img = ArrayHelper::map(app\models\GhsPictogram::find()->all(), 'pictogram_id', 'pictogram_filepath') ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'ghsPictogram',['template'=>'<div class="ghs-pict"> {label}{input} </div>'])->checkboxList($model->imageList($img)) ?>
```

**My imageList method in my model**

```
   public function imageList($filenames) {
        $imageList = [];
        foreach ($filenames as $key => $value) {
            $imageList[$key] = Html::img(
                            Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . 'web' . $value,
                            '', array("style"=>"width: 50px")
            );
        }//foreach $filenames
        return $imageList;  
     }
```

But In my form it doesn't display the image. It instead displays the image src.

I have attached my output:
[image: click here]

Help me find How can I display image in the search form field. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox list has an option called encode, which default to true and it encodes (as it says) html that is passed to it.

To solve it, just add `'encode' => true` to checkboxList options property, like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ghsPictogram',['template'=>'<div class="ghs-pict"> {label}{input} </div>'])->checkboxList($model->imageList($img), [
    'encode' => false
]) ?>
```